# Python-Socket: How to realize recv() and send() at the same time on client side

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

MY **ENVIRONMENT**: windows10 & python 3.6

1. **PURPOSE**: I want to build an online chat room which means when clients are connected to servers and send messages to server, the server will broadcast messages to every clients that have conncetions with it.
2. **KEY POINT**: So there is a problem that i want the client listen to the server and waiting for input at the same time. (*code is posted down below*)
3. **MY SOLUTION**: When I try to solve this problem by *threading* of python, the result is that if let's say client A and client B have both connected to the server and if client A send multiple messages and client B can only receive the first message or receive duplicate & messy messages.  (*imgaes of Error are posted down below*)
4. **EXPLANATION OF CODE** In case my poor develop skills confused you, i want to make a simple explaination of my code.

   1. Before each message was send, the length of the message will be sent first, So it's easy for the recv side to determine how large the buffer should be allocated.
   2. All those "try" and "except" are used to make the system more robust, in case of unexpected disconnection
   3. On the server side, it accept connection requests and deal with each connection  by threads. In each thread, if messages were sent from clients, server will then broadcast the messages to other clients.
   4. On the client side, i create a thread to listen to the messages from server and use "input" to keep waiting for input.
5. **QUESTION** my questions are:
    How can i realize that: any client are free to send as many messages as possible and other clients can reveive all the messages while waiting for the input.(maybe change the way of input?.eg. not use command "input"?)

[image]

**IMAGE EXPLANATION**
1. server is running on the left window and client A is running on the right window and client B is running on the bottom window.
2. the operation in details is: client B sent *"a b c d e"* and client A received *"a"*. client A sent *"a b c e d"* and client B received *"[some info..] a \n [some info..] a"*.
3. We can learn from the image that: when clients send more than one messages before other clients send any messages, then other client will only receive the first message sent by client A or receive duplicate messages.

Finally, sorry for my poor understanding of socket and threading and my poor explanation. Thank you for helping.

```py
code for clinet:

import socket
import time
import threading


SERVER_HOST = "" # server ip
LOCAL_HOST = "10.124.18.206"
HOST = LOCAL_HOST

HEADER = 64
PORT = 42366
CHECK_CLIENT = "!CHECK"
FORMAT = "utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
KEEP_MESSAGE = "KEEP"
TIMEOUT = 50


def gettimestamp():
    return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.localtime())

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER-len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)

def recv():
    message = client.recv(HEADER)
    msg_length = len(message)
    message = message.decode(FORMAT)
    data = client.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
    return data

def listen():
    while True:
        data = recv()
        if data:
            print(f"[MESSAGE {gettimestamp()}] {data}" )
        else:
            break

def start():
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print(f"[STARTING] Connecting to {HOST}:{PORT}")
    client.connect((HOST,PORT))
    send(CHECK_CLIENT)
    client_num = recv()
    print(f"There are {client_num} people in the chat.")
    print("Let's chat!")
    connected = True
    listen_th = threading.Thread(target=listen,args=())
    listen_th.daemon = True
    listen_th.start()
    while connected:
        time.sleep(0.3)
        data = input("[INPUT] ")

        try:
            send(data)
        except ConnectionAbortedError as e:
            connected = False

        if data == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
            connected = False

    print(f"[DISCONNECT {gettimestamp()}] {HOST}:{PORT}")
    client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

```py
code for server

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import threading
import time


SERVER_HOST = "" # server ip
LOCAL_HOST = "10.124.18.206"
HOST = LOCAL_HOST

PORT = 42366
CHECK_CLIENT = "!CHECK"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
HEADER = 64
FORMAT = "utf-8"
TIMEOUT = 60

clients = []

def gettimestamp():
    return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.localtime())

def send(conn,msg):
    try:
        message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
        msg_length = len(message)
        send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
        send_length += b' ' * (HEADER-len(send_length))
        conn.send(send_length)
        conn.send(message)
    except OSError as e:
        print(f"{e} in line 33")
        clients.remove(conn)

def update_chat(msg,conn):
    global clients
    temp = []
    for client in clients:
        flag = 1
        if client != conn:
            try:
                send(client,msg)
            except BrokenPipeError as e:
                print(f"{e} in line 45")
                flag = 0
                continue
        if flag == 1:
            temp.append(conn)

    clients = temp


def handle_client(addr,conn):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION {gettimestamp()}] {addr} connected.")
    print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS {gettimestamp()}] {threading.activeCount()-1}")
    connected = True
    clients.append(conn)
    while connected:
        try:
            conn.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
            msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
            conn.settimeout(None)
            if msg_length:
                msg_length = int(msg_length)
                try:
                    msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
                except ConnectionResetError as e:
                    print(f"{e} in line 67")
                    connected = False
                if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                    connected = False
                    clients.remove(conn)
                elif msg == CHECK_CLIENT:
                    client_num = threading.activeCount()-1
                    send(conn,str(client_num))
                else:
                    update_chat(f"{msg}",conn)

                print(f"[{addr[0]+str(addr[1])} {gettimestamp()}] {msg}")

        except ConnectionResetError as e:
            print(f"{e} in line 81")
            connected = False
        except ConnectionAbortedError as e:
            print(f"{e} in line 84")
            continue
        except socket.timeout as e:
            connected = False


    print(f"[DISCONNECTED {gettimestamp()}] {addr}")

    conn.close()

def start():
    print("[STARTING] Server is starting...")
    server = socket.socket()
    print(f"[BIDING] Binding address {HOST}:{PORT}")
    server.bind((HOST,PORT))
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING {gettimestamp()}] Server is listening on {HOST}:{PORT}")
    while True:
        conn,addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client,args=(addr,conn))
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

Comment: Sleeps in networking code are just literally a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

```
                msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
```

This will receive *up* *to* `msg_length` bytes. You need to ensure you receive *exactly* `msg_length` bytes. You probably want to write a [receive all](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/408859-socketrecv-three-ways-to-turn-it-into-recvall/) function that calls `recv` repeatedly until precisely the required number of bytes are received.

Comment: Thanks for helping！I designed function "recv"  to send the length of message first, before send any message. May be the real problem is not here, cause it stop receiving any messages before the input because of some threading problem.May be the command "input" will block the process, so how do we solve this? or can we avoid this by  another way?

Comment: I have referred to others' implementation of "Online chat room". They keep listening the message from server, while users have to trigger the execution of sending process by clicking or pressing "ENTER" and it won't block for waiting for input.But I still want to know if it's possible to keep listening and sending alternatively and not to be blocked by the command "input"

Comment: I don't understand your comments. I explained what your issue is and how to fix it. Did you understand the explanation?

Comment: Lol. Sorry for my poor English expression.I have modified my code and set the buffer of recv() to a very large value(.eg. 4096).Then i run the server and two clients.And then, i send some very short messages(.eg. a single letter) in short period of  time.But other clients still cannot receive messages except for the first one.

Comment: @leileileijiachen Did you write some kind of "receive all" function that calls `recv` repeatedly until precisely the required number of bytes are received? If not, then you still have the very same problem that I explained in my answer. Using a very large value makes it worse because now you might receive two or more messages in a single call to `recv` and your code has no way to handle that.